# Is it possible to create a constraint on a relationship NEO4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, constraints, relationship

So basically i want to create a constraint on neo4j enterprise edition where the user can't make a relationship in a wrong direction for example:

we got a relationship that occur in this direction
 (a:Com) -[:CONNECTSTO]->(b:Pe) 
And what i need is to constraint that relationship can be made only in that direction, is it possible to make it?

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a constraint to enforce relationship directionality is unnecessary.

Instead, you need to codify your data model (which includes specifying the relationship directionality), have developers understand and follow the data model, and use good testing practices. After any relationship directionality bugs are fixed, they should never accidentally occur (unless someone touches the code).

Such a constraint would also slow down the addition of such relationships. That is overhead you should not need to incur.

Now, suppose such a constraint did exist. You would then have to complicate your code to catch constraint violation exceptions. Not only that, but you'd have to figure out how to recover from such a violation. Since the root problem would be a bug your code, there is really no way to recover except by fixing your code! So, why not just test and fix your code in the first place, thereby making the constraint totally unnecessary. QED.